# iOS 12 simulator black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I installed Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) and running iOS simulator version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-869.5 CoreSimulator-572.2).
iMac (27-inch, Late 2009) OSX High Sierra 10.13.6.

When I start the iPhone X simulator with iOS 12 I get a black screen. I can see the iPhone X phone image but the screen on the simulator is black. Nothing boots up. If I change it to run iPhone 7 with older iOS version it does boot up.

Any clue what could cause this problem?

Comment: Older non-Metal hardware has a bug that is causing this. There is no workaround at this moment, you'll need to use a newer mac or one with a Metal-capable GPU. The issue happens because the iPhone X is an @3x device and so consumes more GPU memory.